# How do I write to a VFP database from an MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-foxpro

I am working with an MVC application, problem is, is it possible to write to a Visual FoxPro database from an MVC application? .. If possible any help in regards with this will be highly appreciated.

**UPDATE**:
I am currently working on a website for a doctor. She wants her clients to be able to make an appointment with her at and given time using the website, which must then link the clients data to VFP software that shes currently using. All i need to do is to be able to take the records of each clients bookings and write it into her current softwares database. The company that created the software for her are granting me access to her database. I am using the code first approach in MVC.

Comment: Use OLEDB connection with VFP OLEDB provider string [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/visual-foxpro/?) or use non-managed COM DLL. Note that your application should enable 32-bit support if required (at this time your question still very broad, please edit with detailed current problem you have).

Comment: Hi, This is my first time attempting this. Apologies if i am not very specific.

Comment: if by "code-first" you mean entity-framework's code-first, that doesn't make much sense if you're trying to connect to a database which already exists. The point of code-first is that you define your classes and then it creates the database structure for you based on that.

Comment: There is a provider available for EF: [VFP EF Provider - Getting Started With Code First](https://randomdevnotes.com/2013/12/15/visual-foxpro-entity-framework-provider-v2-getting-started-with-code-first/). However I recommend using DB First approach with EDM if you want to use existing DB.

Comment: Hi @ADyson I am using the code first approach to create my tables in mvc, the bookings of each client will be stored in this table, but also copied from this table directly into an existing VFP database.

Comment: Is there any reason to write the same data into two places? Why not just read and write everything directly to the VFP database?

Comment: @ADyson Client requirements, she would like to view her data whilst out of the office(MVC), but whilst in the office she wants to use the VFP software. Doesn't make sense to have it in 2 places, but as per her requirements

Comment: @LeevenPersad and MVC can't read the data from VFP and display it, because....why? If MVC can write to VFP, then MVC can read from it as well. If MVC can read from VFP, and MVC is being used to display data to the client while out of office, then problem solved, surely? I fail to see what difference that requirement makes. The MVC app is just another view onto the VFP data.

Comment: @ADyson I completely agree with you on that, though the problem that i face is writing to the VFP database through C#. I don't know how to go about doing that. Everything else is in order, it's just that which i have a problem with

Comment: If you already completely agree with me, why are you doing it differently? As far as I can see you don't need a secondary data store in order to meet the client's requirement. I only mentioned this at all because you talked about code-first, and it didn't make sense. Anyway, Tetsuya has given you links to code libraries which enable you to talk to a VFP database from a .NET application either using OLEDB or even using Entity-Framework (it would be database-first, obviously), or suggested using the COM DLL. Have you looked at any of those yet?

Comment: There's also a lot more stuff online too: https://www.google.co.uk/search?safe=active&ei=ReHdWu3GLZP0gQag-KLQBQ&q=.NET+visual+foxpro+database&oq=.NET+visual+foxpro+database&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i22i30k1.13153.14198.0.14294.9.9.0.0.0.0.136.779.8j1.9.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.9.778...33i22i29i30k1.0.HwW1oVHYw5I

Answer (score 1):

Leveen,

I'm currently doing similar access from MVC to a foxpro db. My MVC is on a different server than the foxpro table.

1. If you had the same setup, I recommend that you use WCF service running on the server where the foxpro database is. Your WCF will need to instantiate a VFP dll which in turn process CRUD requests to your foxpro db.
2. If your IIS is on the same server as the foxpro db, you can skip WCF and instantiate VFP dll directly from MVC.
3. Have you look into VFP Entitiy Framework Provider? https://github.com/tombrothers/VfpEntityFrameworkProvider2

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to handle this. One simple way is to create a separate class library that does all the data access and CRUD operations. Within that DLL, it doesn't really matter if you are doing EF, LinqToVFP, VFP EF or direct ADO.Net commands (I wouldn't suggest COM DLL approach which could be tempting and seem to be easy initially - on the long run you might have frustrations especially with versioning).

You can individually test that class library with or without a web application (from anywhere, like a command window, windows form app, simply using LinqPad etc).

One thing you need to make sure is to enable 32 bit in application pool.